# How to find all scripts which modified a certain vim setting?

Tags: options, startup, debugging

I can figure out which script changed a vim setting the last time with

```
:verbose set errorformat?
```

However, sometimes a setting is modified/appended several times and I want to see all scripts who touched this setting not only the last one.

Right now, I am aware of following means:

1. start vim in verbose mode with

   ```
   $ vim -V15vim.log demo.tex
   ```

   and then grep `vim.log` for the setting (in full and abbreviated form) I am interested in.
2. Grep in vim or on the commandline the directories `~/.vim` and `$VIMRUNTIME`.

Apparently, the event `OptionSet` is deactivated on startup.

Is there a more polished way similar to `:verbose set efm?`?

Related wiki page:

- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Debug_unexpected_option_settings

Answer (score 1):

#### Put vimgrep matches in files from `:scriptnames` into the quickfix list

Using `:scriptnames` allows to consider

- only files which have *actually* been sourced
- and then you can grep for the full and abbreviated option name (regex pattern)

Steps

1. `vim demo.tex` or
   do whatever you need to do to get to the point where you want to find out how you ended up with the current setting.
2. Run `:Scriptnames` from [vim-scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease). This populates the quickfix list with results from `:scriptnames`.
3. Fill arglist from quickfixlist (Is there a better solution?)

   ```
   :argdelete * " if necessary
   :for f in map(getqflist(), {i, v -> bufname(v.bufnr)}) | exe('argadd '.f) | endfor
   ```
4. Search with vimgrep all entries in arglist

   ```
   :vim /\<errorformat\>\|\<efm\>/ ##
   ```

Now one can cycle through likely candidates.

Step 3 and 4 can be combined and avoids to use the arglist:

```
:exe('vimgrep /\<errorformat\>\|\<efm\>/ '.join(map(getqflist(), {i, v -> bufname(v.bufnr)})))
```

However, if you want to try different regex pattern, you might find it better to keep them separated.

If you wish to see a list of files to get a first overview which script is involved, you could run

```
:for f in uniq(sort(map(getqflist(), {i, v -> bufname(v.bufnr)})))| echo f | endfor
```

In my case I get for `/\<errorformat\>\|\<efm\>/`:

```
/Users/hotschke/.vim/pack/lervag/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/qf/latexlog.vim
/Users/hotschke/.vim/pack/tpope/start/dispatch/autoload/dispatch.vim
/Users/hotschke/.vim/pack/tpope/start/fugitive/autoload/fugitive.vim
/Users/hotschke/.vim/pack/tpope/start/projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim
```

However, this is not perfect and it would be better to have something similar for `$ vim -V15vim.log`. But extracting the match and the corresponding file from the log file is more complicated (mostly due to autoloaded functions).